# ZIO-Quill: Conditional update

Tags: zio, zio-quill

I have a requirement to condionally update a table row based on the values provided by the user

```scala
case class Person(id: Long, firstName: Option[String], age: Option[Int], email: Option[String], address: Option[String])
```

if I wan to update a single field with below object

```scala
val person1 = new Person(1, None, None, None, Some("33, xyz st"))
```

in case there are more non None fields, update them too.

There is a sample program here for reference
at [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4AaeqtXeTPafjJDkeGdoIQ)

I couldn't find any examples in the documentation